# Is it possible to retrieve the CDC data that the cleanup job deleted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, change-data-capture

We are using CDC of a SQL Server database for the audit trail of an application.

Data capture was enabled and works correctly, however the retention of the cleanup job was too short and deleted relevant information from the audit trail.

Is there a way to recover the CDC data that was deleted?

If I understand correctly the MS documentation, data should be in the transaction logs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

So I am guessing if it is possible to retrieve the changes from those logs. The recovery mode of the database is "full", the SQL Server are always on high availability.

PS: I am totally new to SQL Server

Adding some context:
we are using a tool to model physical objects for monitoring manufacturing processes. Monitoring requires setting up the assets, events, notifications etc. We are required to have an audit trail for these models.
The information about the models and the audit trail is a database in always on high availability SQL servers. Audit trail works via CDC.

Answer (score 1):

CDC data is just like any other data in your database. Treat this as any other accidental deletion of data. Which is to say, restore the database to a separate location and extract what you need.

Comment: Thank you Ben for your answer:
I would like to understand a thing:
if  I restore the database to a separate location, how can I extract CDC data?

Comment: Check out [cdc.fn_get_all_changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/cdc-fn-cdc-get-all-changes-capture-instance-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (or the analogous net changes function). That said, what was your overall plan when you implemented cdc?

Comment: I am not sure I understand how to make this function work for my case... I got a 0 as a result.

In [cdc].[lsn_time_mapping] the oldest date I can see is 2023-11-21... is there a way to get data cdc data older than this date?


The CDC was created by the application that uses the database, after launching a command that enables the audit trail. CDC capture and cleanup jobs had to be created manually on the secondary replica though
the plan was to have a functioning audit trail of the application.

Comment: In the documentation that I linked to, there is an example that shows how to get all the changes available for a particular table. If you're expecting data from before that, you'll have to restore a backup of your database that has that data in it. As to what your plan is, I get that you want an audit trail. I'm asking *mechanically* what your plan is? Leave the data in the cdc tables forever? Extract it elsewhere? Related, how do you plan to actually *use* the audit data?

Comment: Leave the data in the cdc tables forever?
from my understanding the application is looking in the cdc tables for the audit trail, so yes data should stay in the cdc tables indefinitely.
  
Extract it elsewhere? Related, how do you plan to actually use the audit data?
It is a regulatory requirement to have audit trail available in my industry. Luckly this did not occur in the production system but in a test environment that is required to be equivalent to the production environment.

Comment: my concern with restoring a backup of the database is that I might lose the changes that were done after the backup.

Comment: When I asked "how will you use the data?", I mean, "what queries will you run against it?". When I look at the indexes on the internal CDC table, there's only the clustered index on `__$start_lsn, __$command_id, __$seqval, __$operation`. Conspicuously absent is the primary key. So if this is being used for audit data and you want to track a particular row, you have no choice to scan the entire table. And, I don't know about you, but "table scan" and "infinite retention" don't sound like a party I typically like to attend.

Comment: As to restoring the database, my point was to restore it elsewhere and extract the missing CDC data that you need. Of course, that was on the assumption that you were regularly extracting it and loading it elsewhere. If your plan is to keep it in the CDC tables, you'll have to figure out some way to do that. Again, doesn't sound like my kind of party.

Comment: we are not querying directly the cdc tables, we are using the application instead, I do not  know how it queries the tables, I have to specify start, end, and number of rows.... it is quite slow It's also possible  to create custom code to optimize data filtering and retrieval, we have not done this yet.